# Calculating available bandwidth

Tags: windows, bandwidth

I need write a code in C++ in Windows , to calculate available bandwidth.
I'm currently planing to use spruce algorithm.
i wanted to know is there any code available for this algorithm in windows .
or is there any other technique to get the internet bandwidth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Available bandwidth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273846/available-bandwidth)

Answer (score 2):

Searching for "spruce algorithm" gives me this result http://iris.csail.mit.edu/spruce/ :

> Spruce is a tool for measuring available bandwidth over Internet paths.
>   Download source code

It's GPLv2 and written in C - should be easily portable to C++.

Comment: @Dan D: You may whant to post that as an answer, instead of as a comment.

Comment: @vishal: Correction to my answer: should be easily portable to C++ in Windows. I don't know of a ready-made algorithm to exactly match your specifications; however this seems to use very generic functions, and as such should be simple to adapt for use in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[thrulay](http://shlang.com/thrulay/) is another network capacity tester, which along with calculating the bandwidth, does the rtt and uses median for summarizing delay which as it's author Stanislav Shalunov in [Mean Delay Considered Harmful](http://shlang.com/writing/mean-delay-considered-harmful.html) is right as averages are mostly meaningless if the distribution from which the samples are taken isn't fixed