# Creating C++ client app for some abstract windows server - how to manage TCP connection to server speed?

Tags: c++, performance

So we have some server with some address port and ip. we are developing that server so we can implement on it what ever we need for help. What are standard/best practices for data transfer speed management between C++ windows client app and server (C++)?

My main point is in how to get how much data can be uploaded/downloaded from/to client via his low speed network to my relatively super fast server. (I need it for set up of his live stream Audio/Video bit rate)

My try on explaining number 3.
We do not care how fast is our server. It is always faster than needed. We care about client tyring to stream out to our server his media. he streams encoded (via ffmpeg) live video data to our server. But he has say ADSL with 500kb/s of outgoing traffic. Also he uses some ICQ or what so ever so he has less than 500 kb/s per second. And he wants to stream live video! So we need to set up our ffmpeg to encode video with respect to the bit rate user can provide. We develop server side and client side. We need a way of finding out how much user can upload per second currently (so value can change dynamically over time)

Comment: ofcourse I am intrested in Upload data and download data.

Comment: Standard practice is to transfer as fast as you can? You should probably explain what requirements you have for the transfer speed and what exactly you want to manage with what goals.

Comment: @sth: I tried to explain in more detail - see update.

Comment: Down voter - explain yourself, please?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine its because you provided *NO* details, so the only possible answer is "uh, by doing it quickly.  as quickly as you can."

Comment: @John Dibling: I edited - so what kind of more detailes is needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating available bandwidth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313688/calculating-available-bandwidth)

Comment: I found what is this question duplicating and where is the correct answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted. ["thrulay, network capacity tester"](http://shlang.com/thrulay/) A C++ code library for  Available bandwidth tracking in real time on clients. And there is ["Spruce"](http://iris.csail.mit.edu/spruce/) and it is also oss. It is made using some of linux code but I use Boost library so it will be easy to rewrite.

Offtop: I want to report that there is some group of people on SO down voting on all questions on this topic - I do not know why they are so angry but they deffenetly exist.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Bandwidth_throttling.aspx) Article
it's dot-net but you can try figure out the technique from there.

Comment: Grate one for those who download  +1 But my main point is in how to get how much data can be uploaded from client via his low speed network to my relatively super fast server. (I need it for set up of his live stream Audio/Video bit rate)