# Is there any Algorithm, To find the available bandwidth between two peers on Internet?

Tags: algorithm, generic-programming

I am trying to develop a program which displays the available bandwidth between two peers. Later this module will be integrated in my application which facilitates various user interactions (chatting, desktop sharing etc) using P2P architecture.

Somewhere I read about Spruce algorithm to find the current available bandwidth between two peers, but I am not sure whether that can be used or not.

Is there any already developed algorithm to achieve this ? Plz remember  the architecture is P2P.

this seemed an easier problem when I started working on it, but now I realize it is alot tougher than it looks,.... So I need the help of experienced and enthusiastic network programmers......

thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating available bandwidth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313688/calculating-available-bandwidth)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one.

Send a file and time it. There's your approximate available bandwidth. Need a better approximation? Send a bigger file.

Comment: actually my application works on P2P architecture where time and efficiency is very important.... sending a file to all the peers and than noting the time , is somewhat time consuming and I don't want to use it at least till we accept that there is no other way...

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread on Stackoverflow that is somewhat similar to your question.

[Calculating available bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313688/calculating-available-bandwidth)

Hopefully, you'll find an answer there.